# duplicate html element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

anyone knows of any jquery plugin that handles duplication of some random html elements? I'm looking for a way to dynamically add identical rows to a form.
I know its not hard to make, but i don't really want to reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
The .clone() method, when used in conjunction with one of the insertion methods, is a convenient way to duplicate elements on a page.

```
$('originalSelector').clone().appendTo('selectorToPlaceClone')
```

Answer (score 4):

For a native javascript solution, you can use .cloneNode(true)

```
duplicate = document.getElementById("originalSelector").cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: I've mentioned that I want a jquery solution, if any.

Comment: @Quamis Your title doesn't reflect that and will draw those who want any solution.

Comment: Nifle, based on @RWDJ's suggestion I've added jquery back in the title

Answer (score 0):

Use the native clone method ..

```
$('row_selector_here').clone().appendTo('your_form_selector_here');
```